# Is there any way to use cookies&caches to skip the login process with C# and Playwright?

Tags: c#, json, specflow, playwright

```
using Microsoft.Playwright;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace test;
public class SkipLogin
{

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();

        await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false
        });
        var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions
        {
            StorageState = "userCookies.json"
        });
        var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GotoAsync("https://example.com");
        

    }

}
```

I'm new to C# Playwright and I'm trying to skip the login process by using "userCookies.json".

So, after logging in, I stored all cookies and caches and copied them to my folder. After that, I want to create a browser context with my cookies. But I'm getting this:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ('e' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.) (Interf...

System.AggregateException
One or more errors occurred. ('e' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.) (Interface cannot be resolved: Microsoft.Playwright.IBrowser)
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

I tried it with JavaScript and Playwright it could be doable,but I don't how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their documentation it should be possible. I see you are using `StorageState` maybe try `StorageStatePath` instead. Their example:

```
var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new()
{
    StorageStatePath = "userCookies.json"
});
```

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/auth

It's not clear from their documentation, and I never used this library before and could be wrong, but I believe `StorageState` expects the stringified JSON and not a file path. While `StorageStatePath` expects a file path / file name to the JSON and will read the file for you.

https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.microsoft.playwright/playwright/1.12.1/com/microsoft/playwright/Browser.NewContextOptions.html#storageState

Comment: I also tried it but again its throwing same error. I think I can't skip the login process 

Comment: Can you show how you are saving the userCookies.json and maybe show the JSON itself? Also, can you put the code in a Try Catch and output the exception and stack trace so we can see the line number the error is happening on?

Comment: I wanted to express my gratitude for your helpful and clear comments. They were extremely useful in helping me understand the code and implement it in my project without using the Singleton pattern. It seems that the problem was occurring because I was trying to do it with Singleton. Now that everything is working perfectly, I want to thank you again for your assistance. Your help was greatly appreciated.